# What is peer review work and how does it work?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

How do the edited posts work? I mean while on reviewing the posts from other users, I take some time while editing it. After the edit has been submitted it says your edit will be visible after peer review. What actually is peer review?

Do other people also review the same posts and make edits to the same posts? How is it determined whose edit is going to be shown?

Comment: Peer review is review by your peers (i.e. other SO users, with the appropriate privilege: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). They review **your edit**, not necessarily the post, although they can also choose to add further edits when they accept or reject yours. You cannot submit another edit for review while one is pending. Most of your question is answered in http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing.

Comment: Amazingly, this is not a duplicate of any questions here on Meta.SO. It is, however, a duplicate of a question on the global meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work

Comment: You can find some information about this in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) (scroll down to the bottom).

Comment: Do the moderators with the privilege of reviewing edits earn reputations by reviewing the edits or adding something to the edits?

Comment: @theflash nope, all rep for edits is for users with less than 2k rep and capped at a lifetime 1000rep

Comment: @jonrsharpe Actually, you can have up to 5 pending edits at the same time.

Comment: @dorukayhan a *user* can have five pending edits, I meant a *post* can only have one.

Answer (score 1):

Those with the privilege of approving (reviewing) - those with 2000 reputation - can see the edit and approve or disapprove of it. This is to ensure that you do not open a fresh account and edit as you like. 
More information: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/

Comment: That blog post is _very_ old, and there are more up-to-date answers in the comments.